# The 'SqlStudio Profile Package' package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

When I start up VS 2012 RC I get the following loading error message:

```
The 'SqlStudio Profile Package' package did not load correctly.

The problem may have been caused by a configuration change or by the installation
of another extension. You can get more information by examining the file 
'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.
```

I also have SQL Server 2012 RTM installed.

What can I do to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Open Control Panel
2. Open Programs and Features
3. Locate all items named “Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier App Framework"
   Note: There might be up to 4 such instances all with the above name
4. Right click each of them and select Repair

That should solve this issue.

Answer (score 11):

Janaka solution worked for me.
But if you do not want to lose your VS configuration, remove only the file :

```
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.cache
```

from the folder

```
    %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 Just note that the path is changed based on the VS version for instance for VS 2013 it is under *\12.0\*

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following folders.

C:\Users\UName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
C:\Users\UName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6d35e3d3-81ca-48d0-b4a1-e16dbc2ebc37/vs2010-crashes-on-startup-after-install-of-sp1)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that (in my case), the Data Tools installer has a bug whereby you end up with a registry full of:

Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0Common7

...paths, when it should be:

Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7

Fixing all the values and keys fixes the problem (for me).

(ps: no other solution in this thread worked for me)

Answer (score 1):

Just reinstall [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) (SSDT)

Answer (score 0):

I had to run VS as an administrator in order to clear this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Problem: The 'SqlStudio Profile Package' package did not load correctly.
Proven Solution:
Removing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Default.Cache fixes the problem outlined above. It worked!

Comment: Is there anything new in this answer?